# How do I prevent Bootstrap Tooltips being cloned?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, clonenode

Workarounds:

- Solution #1: Hide the original tooltip - https://jsfiddle.net/LeoTM/p54qzd6q/
- Solution #2: Remove the cloned tooltip - https://jsfiddle.net/LeoTM/m5uy0gkz/

Is there any way to remove the original tooltip?

I have also tried:

- `$(input).tooltip('disable');`
- `$(input).tooltip({ items: ':not(.menu)' });`
- `$(input).tooltip( "option", "disabled", true );`
- `$(input).tooltip({ track: true });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(input).tooltip('destroy');` did the trick.